# would system properties set in one web app contradict another app in the same server?

Tags: java, servlets

If a server is started with a property `java.awt.headless=true`

and if i set a system property in a web application with the context,say `"/web_app1"`, like

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless","false");
```

and from another web app with the context `"/web_app2"`, if i call

```
System.getProperty("java.awt.headless");
```

would it be `true` or `false`..?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that if `web_app2` is started while the system property of the JVM is set to `true` it will still be `true` after `web_app1` has executed the `setProperty` method.

System properties are in the scope of the process and does not leave the boundary of the JVM. They are basically just a key-value mappings of the JVM and it's environment.

This article from the [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMGV_3.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfha2/dfha2al.htm?lang=en) explains it very well.

Looking at the API for [System.setProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperties%28java.util.Properties%29) might be helpful.

Comment: what if the web_app1 has executed the setProperty method, after which the web_app2 is started. Then would web_app2 have the value as false ?

Comment: I'd still say it's true since the server itself had the initial value of `true`, and the `setProperty` that `web_app1` runs is scoped to it's own process and JVM. I assume this might differ depending on what server you are running.

Comment: so if both the apps are in the save JVM it might be conflicting..?

Comment: Apps run independently on their own JVM's normally, but might be loaded to an application server by different classloaders... I have no answer to that last question, perhaps someone else can contribute with their knowledge!

Comment: thank you for your time... Your answer gave me some good to know information.. +1 for that.. :)